# CSS Inheritance Issue - a tag background position

Tags: css, inheritance

I have a social media button-link set that i want to change the position on the background image.
This is the code I have:
HTML:

```
<div id="connections">
    <div id="googleplus"><a target="_blank" href="">&nbsp;</a></div>
    <div id="facebook"><a target="_blank" href="">&nbsp;</a></div>
    <div id="twitter"><a target="_blank" href="">&nbsp;</a></div>
    <div id="youtube"><a target="_blank" href="">&nbsp;</a></div>
    <div id="vimeo"><a target="_blank" href="">&nbsp;</a></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#connections div { display: inline; }

#connections div a {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 0;
    margin: 5px;
}

#connections a { background-position: top center; }

#connections a:hover { background-position: 0 -40px; }

#connections #facebook a { background: url('../images/facebook.png') no-repeat; }
#connections #twitter a { background: url('../images/twitter.png') no-repeat; }
#connections #googleplus a { background: url('../images/googleplus.png') no-repeat; }
#connections #youtube a { background: url('../images/youtube.png') no-repeat; }
#connections #vimeo a { background: url('../images/vimeo.png') no-repeat; }
```

A preview of this can be seen at the bottom of this page -> http://www.bokehcreative.co.uk/about.php

It can be done if I apply !important to the :hover style or apply the hover style to each individual id.

I might be missing a trick here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What *exactly* is your question? Are you saying the `:hover` pseudo-class isn't working as it is?

Comment: Yes, the :hover styling isn't changing the background-position. I've put it down to CSS inheritance but don't understand it enough to know what that problem is. Again, this works with !important but I don't want to use that.

Comment: side note ... unless you are using those IDs elsewhere (which is invalid HTML), you don't need the #connections parent declared. all it does is make your CSS slower.

Comment: My advice is to just use !important.  This is an acceptable use imo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDITED**

Change your parent div IDs to classes and give it a second one for `:hover`.

```
<div id="connections">
    <div class="googleplus connections"><a target="_blank" href="">&nbsp;</a></div>
    <div class="facebook connections"><a target="_blank" href="">&nbsp;</a></div>
    <div class="twitter connections"><a target="_blank" href="">&nbsp;</a></div>
    <div class="youtube connections"><a target="_blank" href="">&nbsp;</a></div>
    <div class="vimeo connections"><a target="_blank" href="">&nbsp;</a></div>
</div>
```

Then apply CSS to the class and get rid of the double-ID specificity of your CSS, use just single parent class declaration:

```
.facebook a { background: url('../images/facebook.png') no-repeat; }
.twitter a { background: url('../images/twitter.png') no-repeat; }
.googleplus a { background: url('../images/googleplus.png') no-repeat; }
.youtube a { background: url('../images/youtube.png') no-repeat; }
.vimeo a { background: url('../images/vimeo.png') no-repeat; }

.connections a:hover { background-position: 0 -40px; }
```

That should avoid any sort of specificity issues. [jsFiddle to show what I mean](http://jsfiddle.net/yKsny/1/) (thanks for the starter, Joseph)

Comment: That's not going to work either.  ids have higher specificity than classes and types: http://jsfiddle.net/yKsny/

Comment: good point, modded my answer. now there should be no specificity conflicts.

Comment: Thanks, this solved it. I'll definitely have to read up on specificity to avoid these types of things in the future.

Comment: just in general, avoid using IDs in CSS whenever possible. you can usually get the same work done with classes, and its a LOT more usable. good article here => http://screwlewse.com/2010/07/dont-use-id-selectors-in-css/